# Spring Jdbc inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm trying for a program in spring which does DB poll and selects that record to read. I see example for xml but i would like to know how do we do in java config. Can someone show me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` `@Bean` definition, marked with the `@InboundChannelAdapter`:

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "fooChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay="5000"))
public MessageSource<?> storedProc(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, "SELECT * FROM foo where status = 0");
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips

Comment: Ok..but how to get that record for processing

Comment: `@ServiceActivator` is there for you to consume messages from the `fooChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: Hi can you explain service  executor method for consuming jdbc record

Comment: The given doc illustration is not working for jdbc i guess

Comment: Seems for me we talk on different languages. The `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` together with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` periodically pool the DB for records and sends messages to the configured channel. To consume those messages in that channel you should declare `@ServiceActivator` with some business service method. What doesn't work by your guess, please?

Comment: I got it ... Thanks